# How to protect Google Speech-To-Text API key if it's on client's computer?

Tags: gcloud, speech-to-text

Quick overview:
The application uses Google's Speech-To-Text to realtime convert the microphone input to text. Because of this, the API key has to be (?) on the cliënt's computer.

It's a webapplication embedded in Electron, so that it has access to the local file system and can start the server that communicates with Google's API. It then sends the received data to the webapplication via a websocket.

What I just realized was that no matter what language I write the server in, a very crafty user might be able to retrieve the API key from the code. How do I protect that key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to only distribute API keys as a last resort; API keys are effectively project-wide bearer tokens with limited constraints as to how they may be used.

You should be able to use service accounts.

Using service accounts you can:

- use >=1 service account for every customer enabling you to enable|disable users at the granularity of one customer or perhaps one customer business unit
- use|assume service account key rotation enabling you to promptly revoke mislaid|shared keys

See:

- https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/#developer_workflow
- https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication

You may wish to consider hosting rather than distributing your server. By hosting the server you increase your control over it, enable more rapid (continuous) updates, bug fixes etc., limit the ability of bad actors to reverse-engineer your code and limit the ability of bad actors to acquire your service account keys.

Comment: Those two problems are connected to each other. Hosting the server ourselfs would eliminate the key/service account problem, but since we're transcribing live audio, we would need seperate threads for each user while connected. We don't have the funds to set up servers that can handle 1000 users sending in audio streams at the same time. What's your advice regarding distribution of those keys to clients?

Comment: Distributing service account keys is better than API keys. You can create accounts per customer (or even finer), you can create multiple keys per account and you can build-in rotation of keys. The keys are essentially bearers though and so you need to ensure your customers treat them as such (if they're paying you for use, they share your motivation to protect them).

Answer (score 1):

I found some documentation about ["Securing an API key"](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#securing_an_api_key) on Google Cloud Platform documentation that could be helpful for you.

Based on this documentation, is recommended to not use API keys directly in your code or in files inside your application's source tree. Instead, you can store them in environment variables or in files outside of your application's source tree.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Ah thanks, I never knew about environment variables, this indeed seems to be the best way to go.